# If a GPO is not the Winning GPO does none or part of the GPO get applied?

Tags: group-policy

I am reviewing some gpresults settings and it shows the Winning GPO as a server configured GPO.   If another GPO has already won and a second GPO tries to set a conflicting settings does the second GPO fail entirely or does it partially apply.

For example:
GPO1 (Winning)

- Use Large Icons: Yes
- Clear recent documents list: No

GPO2

- Use Large Icons: No
- Sort All Programs menu by name: No

Will the "Sort all programs menu by name" be applied or will it not be applied since it is not the winning GPO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will be applied. The `Winning` is relevant to identical settings being applied by each GPO. The `Winning` GPO has precedence and will have it's settings applied. If another GPO configures other settings (not in common with the `Winning` GPO) then it will have those settings set.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/musings_of_a_technical_tam/archive/2012/02/15/understanding-the-structure-of-a-group-policy-object-part-2.aspx